# Visualization of Random Forest Tree in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, random-forest, decision-tree, apache-spark-ml, mlflow

How can I visualize the best Random Forest Tree in RandomForestClassifier, using TrainValidationSplit?

I had no problem displaying a normal decision tree. When I did it this way, I just decomposed the Pipeline.stages[-1] to get a DecisionTree model. But when I do it with RandomForest, it doesn't work because I have many trees.

My goal is to visualize the best tuned Tree-Model, after using param grid search.

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.tuning import ParamGridBuilder, TrainValidationSplit
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
import mlflow

rT = RandomForestClassifier(featuresCol="features",labelCol="label",maxBins=50)

# Pipeline

stagesrT = [indexer, labelToIndex, assembler, rT]

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stagesrT)

evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="label",metricName="accuracy")

grid = ParamGridBuilder() \
  .addGrid(rT.maxDepth, [2, 3, 5, 6]) \
  .addGrid(rT.maxBins, [50, 60, 70, 80]) \
  .addGrid(rT.numTrees, [10,20,30,40,100,200]) \
  .build()

tuning = TrainValidationSplit(estimator=pipeline, evaluator=evaluator, estimatorParamMaps=grid, parallelism=25)

rT.setMinInstancesPerNode(100)

with mlflow.start_run(run_name="random-forrest") as run:  
  
  # Log model
  tunedModel = tuning.fit(trainDF)
  mlflow.spark.log_model(tunedModel, "model")
```

Comment: What *exactly* is your issue? Finding the best performing tree in the RF? (Wouldn't make much sense to visualize it anyway, it is not informative).

Comment: I want to visualize the tree and display the tree depth with the included instances, as well as the feature importance. I need this for the presentation of an algorithm for non-technical people to ensure a better understanding.